# How to parse SQL record to Enum

Tags: sql-server, parsing, enums, datarow

Is there a way to parse enum value from table record. For example, I have class which contains user data, and on of them is Enum type. The data is passed from DataRow, but I have trouble parsing enum value.
I tried something like this,

```
uType= (EType) Enum.TryParse(typeof(row["userType"]));
```

but it wouldn't compile. Any tip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code

```
uType = (EType) Enum.Parse(typeof(EType), row["userType"].ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) returns a boolean that indicates if the value could be parsed successfully.

Assuming that `userType` is a `string` in the `DataTable`:

```
EType eType;
bool canParse = Enum.TryParse(row.Field<String>("userType"), out eType);
```

Comment: Yes, this also works as the code from @Candie! Thank you both!